# Rails service object returning 'No Method error'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-object

To begin: This is my first attempt at getting business logic out of the Model/controller space.  Here is some initial logic I'm trying to abstract. The path is `app/services/Date_calc.rb`.

```
class Date_calc
  require User
  require Report

  def months(range)
    User.first.reports.order("report_month desc").limit(range).pluck(:report_month)
  end
end
```

In my application I have two models, User and Reports. User has_many Reports. The `reports` table has a field called `report_month`.

Calling `Date_calc.months(6)` in the Rails console returns: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Class into String`.

My intended response was an array of dates, e.g. `["01/01/2013", "01/02/2013", "01/03/2013", ... ]`.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the require lines lacking quote marks, you are calling an instance method on a class. You either need to instantiate the Date_calc like this

```
months = Date_calc.new.months(6)
```

or make it a class method like this

```
def self.months(range)...
```

Comment: the ".new" did the trick. And Ive seen this [elsewhere](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) but since the subject was adding users it seemed like they were calling a new record, similar to User.new, it didnt occur to me.

Comment: It works, but does it make sense? What does `Date_calc.new` really mean? What are you creating an instance of?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `require` expects a String (e.g. `require "path_to_module"`) but you're giving it a Class:

```
require User
require Report
```

If this is running in Rails, then Rails will autoload both of these classes. You don't need to do `require` at all.

**Edit:** After you've removed those lines, `Date_calc.months(6)` is still going to give you a NoMethodError, because `months` is an instance method, but you're trying to call it as though it's a class method. You either need to call it on an instance of the Date_calc class, like this:

```
Date_calc.new.months(6)
```

Alternatively, you could define it as a class method by doing `def self.months(range)` instead of `def months(range)`, which would allow you to call `Date_calc.months(6)`. But you might want to think about whether or not Date_calc should actually be a class, or if it should be a module.

It should be a class if you want to have multiple instances of it, like you would want an instance of a User or instance of a Report. "User" and "Report" are both nouns, because the class represents a *thing* that we might want to have more than one of. Does the sentence "I want to create a Date_calc" make sense? How about the sentence "I want to create two Date_calcs"? If you said yes to both, then a class makes sense.

If, however, you just want something to put some related methods in, but that doesn't represent a *thing*, then you might want to use a module instead. In Rails, for example, the `Rails` object is not a class, it's a module. It doesn't make sense to say "I want to create a Rails," much less "I want to create two Rails." Rails is just a module used to group related methods together. If Date_calc fits that description, then it makes more sense as a module:

```
module Date_calc
  def self.months(range)
    # ...
  end
end

# and then...
Date_calc.months(6)
```

As you can see, we use `def self.months` instead of `def months`, because we want to be able to call the method on the module itself.

Comment: Thats what I tried at first, which yields: NoMethodError: undefined method `months' for Date_calc:Class

Comment: That error is because of the way you're calling `months`, not because Date_calc hasn't been included (it has). I've updated my answer to explain.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, having only recently accomplished 'Post.all', this one was baffling. Your comments were the answer i needed.